# JavaScript - Continue after IF statement ends

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a simple solution. Right now I use multiple if statements, and of course it ends after the first one is true. Currently I have a list of things that need to be executed after the previous one has ended. I'm sure there is a simple solution, but unfortunately I don't know it yet.

Here is my code:

```
function writesolutions() {
            document.write("<article><p id=\"solutions_title\" class=\"ticketsubtitlesolutions\">Details oplossingen</p><div id=\"solutions_details\" class=\"ticketdetails_container\">");

            if (pageloadsolution != null); {
                document.writeln('<p id="paginaladen" class="semisubtitle">Pagina laadt niet</p><p class="helpdescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>');
            };
            if (pagespeedsolution != null); {
                document.writeln('<p id="paginasnelheid" class="semisubtitle">Pagina laadt traag</p><p class="helpdescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>');
            };
            if (kiestoonsolution != null); {
                document.writeln('<p id="kiestoon" class="semisubtitle">Geen kiestoon</p><p class="helpdescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>');
            };
            if (vastnaarmobielsolution != null); {
                document.writeln('<p id="vastnaarmobiel" class="semisubtitle">Vast naar mobiel bellen</p><p class="helpdescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>');
            };
            if (mobielnaarvastsolution != null); {
                document.writeln('<p id="mobielnaarvast" class="semisubtitle">Mobiel naar vast bellen</p><p class="helpdescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>');
            };
            if (splittersolution != null); {
                document.writeln('<p id="aansluitingsplitter" class="semisubtitle">Splitter niet correct aangesloten</p><p class="helpdescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>');
            };
            if (setupboxsolution != null); {
                document.writeln('<p id="aansluitingsetupbox" class="semisubtitle">Setupbox niet correct aangesloten</p><p class="helpdescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>');
            };
            if (zenderssolution != null); {
                document.writeln('<p id="detectiezenders" class="semisubtitle">Zenders worden niet gevonden</p><p class="helpdescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>');
            };
            document.write("</div></article>");
        };
```

Thank you very much in advance! :D

Comment: try deleting pretty much every `;` in your code, apart from the ones at the end of the `document.write` lines and you should be ok - currently the code is syntactically valid but not doing at all what you expect

Comment: beside @Rhumborl 's important comment, adding 'else' before every if will do the job.

Comment: why would you add an ";" after every if statement. And this code would execute like there are no if conditions at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me point out the syntax error first.

Next to all the if condition parenthesis you added ";" which should not be there. Try removing that.

> if (pageloadsolution == 5)

As it is seen you are checking different values in all the if conditions. so in your function you can accept arguments the number of arguments can be based on the conditions you want to check.

```
function writesolutions(pageloadsolution,pagespeedsolution,kiestoonsolution,vastnaarmobielsolution,mobielnaarvastsolution,splittersolution,setupboxsolution,zenderssolution)
```

so the final code will look like this

```
function writesolutions(pageloadsolution,pagespeedsolution,kiestoonsolution,vastnaarmobielsolution,mobielnaarvastsolution,splittersolution,setupboxsolution,zenderssolution) {
            document.write("<article><p id=\"solutions_title\" class=\"ticketsubtitlesolutions\">Details oplossingen</p><div id=\"solutions_details\" class=\"ticketdetails_container\">");

            if (pageloadsolution == 5) {
                document.writeln('<p id="paginaladen" class="semisubtitle">Pagina laadt niet</p><p class="helpdescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>');
            };
            if (pagespeedsolution == 5) {
                document.writeln('<p id="paginasnelheid" class="semisubtitle">Pagina laadt traag</p><p class="helpdescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>');
            };
            if (kiestoonsolution == 5) {
                document.writeln('<p id="kiestoon" class="semisubtitle">Geen kiestoon</p><p class="helpdescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>');
            };
            if (vastnaarmobielsolution == 5) {
                document.writeln('<p id="vastnaarmobiel" class="semisubtitle">Vast naar mobiel bellen</p><p class="helpdescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>');
            };
            if (mobielnaarvastsolution == 5) {
                document.writeln('<p id="mobielnaarvast" class="semisubtitle">Mobiel naar vast bellen</p><p class="helpdescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>');
            };
            if (splittersolution == 5) {
                document.writeln('<p id="aansluitingsplitter" class="semisubtitle">Splitter niet correct aangesloten</p><p class="helpdescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>');
            };
            if (setupboxsolution == 5) {
                document.writeln('<p id="aansluitingsetupbox" class="semisubtitle">Setupbox niet correct aangesloten</p><p class="helpdescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>');
            };
            if (zenderssolution == 5) {
                document.writeln('<p id="detectiezenders" class="semisubtitle">Zenders worden niet gevonden</p><p class="helpdescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>');
            };
            document.write("</div></article>");
        };

        writesolutions(5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, the variables are, depending on a previous function, filled (or not). For example, when someone has an issue, the pageloadsolution has the fill "issue" and therefore "not null".

How do I convert that to your edit?

Comment: Since the variables are depend upon previous function one way to do is set the variables in the previous function as global variables. so the values are available everywhere and when this function is called it will check for the values and execute

Answer (score 2):

```
function writesolutions() {
            document.write("<article><p id=\"solutions_title\" class=\"ticketsubtitlesolutions\">Details oplossingen</p><div id=\"solutions_details\" class=\"ticketdetails_container\">");

            if (pageloadsolution != null){
                document.writeln('<p id="paginaladen" class="semisubtitle">Pagina laadt niet</p><p class="helpdescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>');
            }
            if (pagespeedsolution != null){
                document.writeln('<p id="paginasnelheid" class="semisubtitle">Pagina laadt traag</p><p class="helpdescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>');
            }
            if (kiestoonsolution != null){
                document.writeln('<p id="kiestoon" class="semisubtitle">Geen kiestoon</p><p class="helpdescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>');
            }
            if (vastnaarmobielsolution != null); {
                document.writeln('<p id="vastnaarmobiel" class="semisubtitle">Vast naar mobiel bellen</p><p class="helpdescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>');
            }
            if (mobielnaarvastsolution != null){
                document.writeln('<p id="mobielnaarvast" class="semisubtitle">Mobiel naar vast bellen</p><p class="helpdescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>');
            }
            if (splittersolution != null){
                document.writeln('<p id="aansluitingsplitter" class="semisubtitle">Splitter niet correct aangesloten</p><p class="helpdescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>');
            }
            if (setupboxsolution != null){
                document.writeln('<p id="aansluitingsetupbox" class="semisubtitle">Setupbox niet correct aangesloten</p><p class="helpdescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>');
            }
            if (zenderssolution != null){
                document.writeln('<p id="detectiezenders" class="semisubtitle">Zenders worden niet gevonden</p><p class="helpdescription">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>');
            }
            document.write("</div></article>");
        };
```

Rhumborl is right there is too many semi-colons there you go!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon after the closing brace of your if statement, like so:

```
 if (splittersolution != null) {
```

Comment: The code still does not work, but thanks for your comment! Pretty stupid mistake I made there...

Comment: removing the semicolon will have no effect on the result. Check my answer below. the code works

Answer (score 0):

return "true" for continue to next if condition and return "false" to stop and exit

```
if (pageloadsolution != null){
    document.writeln('<p id="paginaladen">id est laborum.</p>');
    return true;//continue for next step
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your question, but i think you should refactor your code so it's more handy.
Rather then using a bunch of variables, you should store all possible flags and the corresponding data in a dictionary (=a plain Object in Javascript).

Example :

```
var FlagsData = {
    pageLoad : { text : 'some text for page load'},
    pageSpeed : { text : 'some text for page speed' },
    ...
}

var currentFlag = 'pageLoad';
```

Then your writesolution becomes much simpler :

```
function writesolutions(flag) {
        document.write("<article><p id=\"solutions_title\" class=\"ticketsubtitlesolutions\">Details oplossingen</p><div id=\"solutions_details\"class=\"ticketdetails_container\">");
        var text=FlagsData[flag].text;
        document.write('<p id="paginaladen" class="' + flag +'">' + text + '</p>');
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, I just started with JavaScript so I've no idea what you're talking about... :(